# pop() removing value from multiple lists in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

```
def create_deck():
    """
    A function that creates a full 52-card deck\n
    :return: dict
    """
    suits = ["hearts", "diamonds", "spades", "clubs"]
    cards = ["A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K"]

    # Creates a full deck of cards with dictionary comprehension
    # using the indices from the list suits as keys
    deck_of_cards = {suit: cards for suit in suits}
    return deck_of_cards


def select_card(deck_dictionary):
    """
    A function that selects a single card from a 52-card deck.
    Return the card face name, number and value\n
    :return: tuple
    """
    import random
    deck = deck_dictionary
    random_suit = random.choice([x for x in deck])
    # random_card = random.choice(range(len(deck[random_suit]) - 1))
    # card = deck[random_suit].pop([random_card])
    # return random_suit, card
    random.shuffle(deck[random_suit])
    card = deck[random_suit].pop(0)
    return card, random_suit, deck


deck_obj = create_deck()
print(deck_obj)
print(select_card(deck_obj))
print(select_card(deck_obj))
```

OUTPUT
Original Deck

```
{'hearts': ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'], 'diamonds': ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'], 'spades': ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K'], 'clubs': ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'J', 'Q', 'K']}
```

First Pass Through select_card()

```
('Q', 'hearts', {'hearts': ['7', '10', '6', '9', '4', '2', 'K', '8', 'J', '5', 'A', '3'], 'diamonds': ['7', '10', '6', '9', '4', '2', 'K', '8', 'J', '5', 'A', '3'], 'spades': ['7', '10', '6', '9', '4', '2', 'K', '8', 'J', '5', 'A', '3'], 'clubs': ['7', '10', '6', '9', '4', '2', 'K', '8', 'J', '5', 'A', '3']})
```

Second Pass through select_card()

```
('5', 'hearts', {'hearts': ['10', '9', '6', '4', '7', 'A', '8', 'J', 'K', '3', '2'], 'diamonds': ['10', '9', '6', '4', '7', 'A', '8', 'J', 'K', '3', '2'], 'spades': ['10', '9', '6', '4', '7', 'A', '8', 'J', 'K', '3', '2'], 'clubs': ['10', '9', '6', '4', '7', 'A', '8', 'J', 'K', '3', '2']})
```

If you can see I am removing the 'card' variable in each list instead of removing it in the selected 'random_suit' list.

I've been at this a few hours.
The returns are just for testing at the moment.

I also tried:

```
def create_deck():
    """
    A function that creates a full 52-card deck\n
    :return: dict
    """
    royals = {"J": 10, "Q": 10, "K": 10}
    suits = ["hearts", "diamonds", "spades", "clubs"]
    cards = list(range(2, 11))
    cards += royals.items()

    # Creates a full deck of cards with dictionary comprehension
    # using the indices from the list suits as keys
    # and set all values with the cards variable - 2 through to 10 and adding royal cards
    deck_of_cards = {suit: cards for suit in suits}
    return deck_of_cards
```

```
def select_card(deck_dictionary):
    """
    A function that selects a single card from a 52-card deck.
    Return the card face name, number and value\n
    :return: tuple
    """
    import random
    deck = deck_dictionary
    random_suit = random.choice([x for x in deck])
    random_card = random.choice(range(len(deck[random_suit]) - 1))
    if random_card > 8:
        card = list(deck[random_suit][random_card])
        (deck[random_suit])
        return deck
        return random_suit, card
    else:
        card = deck[random_suit][random_card]
        del deck[random_suit][random_card]
        return deck
        return random_suit, card
```

This has the same result as the previous code above, removing the element in every list not the intended 'random_suit'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that each suit gets the same list of cards - the same instance - which you are then modifying (sorting and removing from). You can ask for a copy, instead:

```
deck_of_cards = {suit: cards.copy() for suit in suits}
```

Comment: So the value for each key is actually pointing to the same spot in memory? When I remove an element I'm removing it from that point?

Is that the gist of it?

Comment: Yep, that's more or less it. This talk by Ned Batchelder has better explanations (and pictures!), if you want to know more: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with lists/dictionaries, it is important to remember that assignment such as:

```
listA = [1,2,3]
listA = listB
```

do NOT copy your list. and you can see if you change an element of listA, listB will change accordingly:

```
listA[2] = 4
print(listB)
# This will output [1,2,4]
```

Thus when assigning lists, you will need to copy. There are multiple methods but two that I suggest are:

```
listA = listB[:]
```

and

```
listA = listB.copy()
```

the first method works with older python, while the 2nd needs python3+ as far as I know